# Racket: keep getting the error "while: unbound identifier in: while"

Tags: racket

```
    (define (sort_list lst [res '()] [temp (cdr lst)] [n (length lst)] [unsorted #t] [x 0])
  ((while unsorted
         ((for ([i lst])
            (set! x 0)
            (for ([j temp])
              (when (<= i j)
                  (add1 x)))
            (when (equal? x n)
              ((cons i res) (set! lst (cdr lst)) (set! temp (cdr temp)) (sub1 n)))
            )
          )
         (when (empty? lst) (set! unsorted #f))
         )
  res))
```

trying to write a function that sorts a list of integers

Comment: `while` isn't defined by `#lang racket` or `#lang racket/base` or others. See [syntax-parse-examples](https://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax-parse-example/index.html#%28form._%28%28lib._syntax-parse-example%2Fwhile-break%2Fwhile-break..rkt%29._while%29%29) for one possible implementation.

Comment: Normally you'd use recursion in the form of a named let or whatever instead. Or just `(sort lst <)`.

Comment: If you really want to write your own list sorting routine, look into merge sort. It plays very nicely with linked lists.

Comment: (You have a bunch of issues with that code, like extra parenthesis making things that aren't functions be treated like they're supposed to be (Which will generate errors))

Comment: @Shawn Its for an assignment where i have to make a non-recursive list sorting function with hofs. I am new to racket as well so it makes sense there are a lot of issues. Thanks for the help

Comment: You *can't* avoid recursion in Scheme and Racket. Even things that *look* like iteration are actually recursive even if it's hidden a bit. Great for discovering that recursion and iteration are just two sides of the same coin.

Comment: Looks like you know a thing or two about algol languages and try to assimilate Scheme. It's like trying to speak Greek based on your knowledge of Frensh and Spanish. Scheme isn't algol so you'll need to do a few things quite differently.

Comment: @Sylwester yeah thats the hardest part for me right now. I can visualize exactly how to solve the problems but I just can't translate them correctly into Scheme